# Pyqt Session management error

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

When I run Pyuic with my UI file, It gives the following error.

```
# pyuic detector.ui Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'detector.ui'
#
# Created: Sat Dec 24 07:32:27 2011
#      by: The PyQt User Interface Compiler (pyuic) 3.18.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from qt import *
```

Its as a root user. When I run as a normal user It doesnt give the first line: "Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported". But it doesnt create any file.

I am having debian squeeze

Comment: This is not `pyqt4`. It's `pyqt3`, which is more or less dead.

Comment: The error hasn't even got anything to do with pyqt3 (which is [still supported](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download3) btw).

Comment: Apparently it did since he had to remove the old pyqt tools and replace with pyqt4 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the `pyqt-tools` package and installed the `pyqt4-dev-tools` package which includes the `pyuic4`. Now everything works fine.

Thank you @Blender for pointing me to the solution